# Google Adsense: can you really get approved for Adsense program with a site like this?

Tags: adsense, ads

Here's a site with no real content, click any link in the "navigation", you'll see nothing other than ads, ads and tons of Google Ads. I hear people getting rejected from the program for various reasons but **is this site real**, **is it hosting real Google Adsense ads**? I have checked the HTML and it doesn't seem to be a "fake Google Adsense" site.

http://linuxosr.com/[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not the most experienced at Google AdSense, but I implemented their advertisements on a few websites. What I can tell you is, at least in my case, once you are initially approved to display ads on your first site, it is nearly effortless to display ads on other websites. You do not have to go through a reapplication/verification/etc; you just have to adhere to Google's policies on every website on which you implement the advertisements.

In regards to [linuxosr.com](http://linuxosr.com/), I believe it is just a service, called "[Cash Parking](http://www.godaddy.com/parking/domain-name-parking.aspx)," provided by GoDaddy.com to help monetize views while the domain is not in use. It may or may not be subject to the same policies Google places on "real" websites.

Comment: Does it mean that if Google approved a site, they will not check again and again if the website is still complying with the approvement criteria?

Comment: No, they continually monitor the sites to ensure compliance with their policies. Here is [Google's official word](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1282103?hl=en) on your question. It would be rather naive of them to approve a site and never check it again; there would be countless "spam" sites using their advertisements if that were the case! Edit: Note that if just one of the websites using advertisements from your AdSense account is caught not complying with their policies, all of the websites on your account could be affected!

Comment: So this guy is likely to get removed from the Adsense program if a Google employee reviews this site or is this kind of "cash parking" accepted? I am currently trying to gather information on what criteria a website needs to meet to be eligible for Adsense and see that people with far less "violations" of the webmaster rules get rejected than this scam site.

Comment: With "Cash Parking," the owner of the domain has a contract with GoDaddy and not Google AdSense. That means that Google has the ability to do whatever they want and not alert the owner of anything. Here is [such an example](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/fvPa0tpdIRc). If you created a website such as this one and placed advertisements on it using your own Adsense account, it would not likely pass compliance, as "your web site must have a unique, relevant content."